# Find specific menu item in Excel custom menu

Tags: excel, vba, menuitem

In Excel (2010) I have created a menu

```
Dim NewMenu As CommandBarPopup
Set NewMenu = CommandBars(1).Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlPopup, Before:=HelpMenu.Index, temporary:=True)
NewMenu.Caption = "&MyMenu"
```

and added some items into it

```
Dim MenuItem As CommandBarControl
Set MenuItem = NewMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton)
With MenuItem
    .Caption = "&Item1..."
    .Tag = "Item1"
End With
```

**Now later, how can I find a specific menu item with VBA**, to enable or disable it for example?

I tried the below

```
Dim itm As CommandBarControl
For Each itm In Application.CommandBars(1).Controls("&MyMenu")
    If itm.Tag="Item1" Then ...
Next
```

but "Object doesn't support this type or method" error appears.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to loop you can directly address that `Item`. For example

```
Dim ctlItm As CommandBarControl

Set ctlItm = NewMenu.Controls("Item1...")
```

Comment: How could I miss it?)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code. It works for me:

```
Dim itm As CommandBarControl
For Each itm In Application.CommandBars(1).Controls("&MyMenu").Controls
   If itm.Tag = "Item1" Then
      'do something
   End If
Next
```